# PLSQL command insert into select from gives unique constraint error

Tags: plsql

I'm new to plsql and this command is screwing up something:

```
insert into coffee_tea_join_table 
select coffee_id, 16 
from coffee_tea_join_table 
where tea_id = 6;
```

This returns a

> "Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated"
>   error.

The coffee_tea_join_table only has two columns, coffee_id and a tea_id.

It looks like the statement wants to insert something again that's from the same table it's selecting from. I'm guessing it looks for the coffee_id table where the corresponding tea_id = 6, but why is the '16' static value there? There is no '16' column...

If it finds a coffee_id where tea_id = 6, then why does inserting it into the same table again make sense? Maybe that's why the constraint was violated?

Comment: Most likely it's trying to insert 16 for each coffee_id where it has a tea_id =6. Which means this statement may not be the cause. Rather, some other script is inserting wrong data before this executes...

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to have a look into unique indexes and primary keys of your table, after it check how many records are extracted by your query. I hope you get only 1 rec.   If many - consider about triggers. May be some of them overrides your 16 (from wrong sequence for instance). At any case please provide us the ddl of the table with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If we start with assuming that table coffee_tea_join_table have two columns coffee_id and tea_id and that the table have a combine unique constraint for these two tables. The SQL is creating a new record with the tea_id = 16 and cofee_id the same as for the record with tea_id = 6. This error is then caused by the fact that you already have a record with tea_id = 16 and cofee_id = the same cofee_id value as the record with tea_id = 6.

If this is not helping you then you need to dig out the table definition including the unique constraints of the table.